# Why is this textfield losing focus with morphdom?

Tags: javascript, dom, virtual-dom

Here's a contrived example below that isolates my problem. There's a simple text field w/ a message that displays if the character count is even. If I move the message below the textfield it seems morphdom sees that only the value of the textfield has changed, so it doesn't rebuild the input node which mean the control keeps focus. If I keep the message above the textfield, morphdom rebuilds the control despite the fact that I'm specifying an id.

From the docs...

https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/morphdom

> In addition, the algorithm used by this module will automatically match up elements that have corresponding IDs and that are found in both the original and target DOM tree.

Code Example...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOvZJz

```
var text = "";
var origRootDiv = null;
function createView() {
  var rootDiv = document.createElement("div");

  // If moved under, issue goes away
  if (text.length > 0 && text.length % 2 == 0) {
    var messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
    messageDiv.innerHTML = "Even char count!";
    rootDiv.appendChild(messageDiv);
  }
  // End if

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "this-should-help-right";
  input.value = text;
  rootDiv.appendChild(input);
  input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    text = e.target.value;
    var newRootDiv = createView();
    morphdom(origRootDiv, newRootDiv);
  });

  return rootDiv;
}
origRootDiv = createView();
document.body.appendChild(origRootDiv);
```

**EDIT**

The current behavior is that if you type 1 character in the field the text field retains focus (good), but if you type a second character in the field and the "Even char count!" message is shown the textfield loses focus (bad).

The desired behavior is that even if the message is shown, the textfield should retain focus.

Comment: From your question, do you want to reset the input field when you click outside?

Comment: @saifudeenni No. I added some more info to the question, hoping that clarifies. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

**Add `.focus()` to the input by using `id`.**
see this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_text_focus.asp

### Solution

See the updated code,

```
input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      text = e.target.value;
      var newRootDiv = createView();
      morphdom(origRootDiv, newRootDiv);

      // added the input with Id here
      document.getElementById('this-should-help-right').focus();
    });
```

I have added `document.getElementById('this-should-help-right').focus();` after `morphdom` call. So i think the problem is solved

Comment: While this works for this simple example (which I created solely toe demonstrate the issue), it's not ideal for my app which uses morphdom to render the whole app. Having to track which field is focused w/in the app and refocus it everytime I render the UI is a pain. I'm assuming morphdom supports this use case and am hoping there's just something I'm doing wrong w/ the library.

Comment: Need to manually set focus defies the whole point of having morphdom.